# Change the order of a column

Tags: r

I am struggling to order column in my dataset. The way I want to reorder can be shown in the following example:

I have the following data:

```
dd = data.frame("AssignedA"=1:2, "AverageA"=1, "AssignedB"=1, "AverageB"=1,
  "AssignedC"=1, "AverageC"=1, "ValueA"=1, "ValueB"=1, "ValueC"=1)
```

For an easy overview, I would like the columns to be ordered in the following way:

> Assigned A - Assigned B - Assigned C - Average A - Average B - Average C-  Value A - Value B - Value C

How to do this? I couldn't find the solution in questions posted earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep things simple and use `seq` to create the order of the columns. First, (and you should do this in your question), create some dummy data:

```
dd = data.frame("AssignedA"=1:2, "AverageA"=1, "AssignedB"=1, "AverageB"=1,
  "AssignedC"=1, "AverageC"=1, "ValueA"=1, "ValueB"=1, "ValueC"=1)
```

then just reorder as usual:

```
dd[,c(seq(1,6,2), seq(2,6,2), 7:9)]
```

Here, the command in the `[]` specifies the order:

```
R> c(seq(1,6,2), seq(2,6,2), 7:9)
[1] 1 3 5 2 4 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: That really is simple.. Works perfectly!